# using property of a class in another

Tags: c#, winforms, class, picturebox, chess

i have a simple question.how can i use property of a class  in another class in ?i have a picturebox in a class and i want to use the picture in picturebox in another class.how can i do it?thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edit: this answer relates to when the question referred to *tabs*)

Unless I have misunderstood the question, a couple of options:

- have two separate instances of the `PictureBox` and associated image
- sneakily re-position the `PictureBox` when the tab index changes (small saving on resources)

Comment: @arash - then the second part of the answer no longer applies. Ultimately, though, `PictureBox` is a UI component; that isn't really aimed at sharing/re-use; you could perhaps share the underlying *image* though